# How to find updated jar of grizzly?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, repository, grizzly

I'm having this problem with Glassfish ([Link](http://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1375?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin%3aactivity-stream-issue-tab)) and to fix it I need to update Glassfish's Grizzly version to 1.9.55 but I can't find it anywhere !
Does anyone now how to get this fix ?
Thanks

Comment: If I overwrite the old jar, I get this error during startup: BundleException: 
Unresolved constraint in bundle org.glassfish.main.core.kernel [176]: 
Unable to resolve 176.0: missing requirement [176.0] osgi.wiring.package; 
(&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.appserv.server)(version>=3.1.0)) 
[caused by: Unable to resolve 86.0: missing requirement [86.0] osgi.wiring.package; 
(&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.grizzly.tcp)(version>=1.9.0)) 
[caused by: Unable to resolve 115.0: missing requirement [115.0] osgi.wiring.package; 
(&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.grizzly.lzma)(version>=1.9.55))]]

Comment: Clearing the osgi-cache folder does not help. How did you manage to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is referenced on [grizzly.java.net](http://grizzly.java.net/), [1.9.55](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/sun/grizzly/grizzly-utils/1.9.55/grizzly-utils-1.9.55.jar)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the attached `grizzly-utils.jar` *(version 1.9.46)*.

In order to patch GlassFish, copy the [attached jar file](https://java.net/jira/secure/attachment/51900/grizzly-utils-1.9.46.jar) to the `glassfishv3/glassfish/modules` folder and overwrite existing `grizzly-utils.jar`.